# spring-data-elasticsearch latest version throws NullPointer exception with Elasticsearch 8.1 version

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

> ```
> Planning to use elasticsearch 8.1 version and use 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch' in
> ```
>
> our project.
> Repository.save() throws following exception.
> java.lang.NullPointerException: null
> at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:221)
> at org.elasticsearch.action.DocWriteResponse.(DocWriteResponse.java:116)
> at org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexResponse.(IndexResponse.java:43)
>
> ```
> The same code with Elasticsearch 7.15.2 works fine.
>
> I see the supported matrix  here https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#preface.requirements
> Where to see the road map of Spring boot elasticsearch data plugin? When Do we get the plugin support for the 8.1 version of
> ```
>
> Elasticsearch?
> Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following headers resolved the issue.

```
Accept: "application/vnd.elasticsearch+json;compatible-with=7"
Content-Type: "application/vnd.elasticsearch+json;compatible-with=7"
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better to change your code which is used for creating client

```
package com.search.elasticsearchapp.config;

import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClientBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.config.EnableElasticsearchRepositories;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;

@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "*")
public class TestClient {

    @Value("${elasticsearch.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${elasticsearch.port}")
    private int port;

    @Value("${elasticsearch.protocol}")
    private String protocol;

    @Value("${elasticsearch.username}")
    private String userName;

    @Value("${elasticsearch.password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public RestHighLevelClient restClient() {

        final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(userName, password));

        RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(host, port, protocol))
                .setHttpClientConfigCallback(httpClientBuilder -> httpClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider))
                .setDefaultHeaders(compatibilityHeaders());

        return new RestHighLevelClient(builder);
    }

    private Header[] compatibilityHeaders() {
        return new Header[]{new BasicHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, "application/vnd.elasticsearch+json;compatible-with=7"), new BasicHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/vnd.elasticsearch+json;compatible-with=7")};
    }
}
```